# How can ı change my logo for specific page?

Tags: multisite

ı want to change this page's logo

( https://kgyou.nl/home-ballonnen/ )

to

https://kgyou.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/KG_You_Ballonnen_sRGB.png

ı looked logo class

```
    .page-id-7949 .default-logo lazyloaded{

   background: url(wp-content/uploads/2021/07/cropped-KG_You_Ballonnen_sRGB.png) no-repeat; 
 }
```

but it didnt work why ?

Comment: I can't see that page (I just get "binnenkort") but I'd guess you don't want the lazyloaded there: that would mean a `<lazyloaded>` tag that's a descendant of the tag with class default-logo, which looks wrong to me.

Comment: However I'd probably do this by writing a filter for theme_mod_custom_logo that changes the attachment ID returned for that one page. Or maybe more generally check if the current page has a specific meta property and use that as the ID instead when present (if that doesn't cause an extra database read on every page)